# Regex validate only part even with \w

Tags: regex

I am looking at someone else code and am missing some detail as why it is not working.

```
Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl().match(/http:\/\/\w+/) + ":5556/" + Xrm.Page.context.getOrgUniqueName() + "/REST/";
```

It only delivers part of the IP-address the rest work.

```
http//:789.789.789.123
```

becomes

```
http//:123:5556/UniqueName/REST/
```

`\w+` should take everything after http://. Those validations I have looked at use /http://

Comment: There is no way that regex can match an IP address: `\w` does not match the dot char `.`.

Comment: Match is probably a sloppy way to express my self. I don't need to check the quality of the url just make it a variables. that I can combine with two other variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\w+` does not take everything. It only takes "word characters", i.e., letters, digits, and other locale-dependent "word characters" <sup>note</sup>. Whitespaces and **punctuation marks** aren't matched against `\w` <sup>note</sup>.

You probably want `[\d.]+`, which takes one or more repetitions of digits and dots, or `\S+` for everything except whitespaces.

---

Note: The underscore `_` is considered a "word character", so it *will* be matched by `\w`.

Comment: This can serve as a nice reminder that `\w`/`\W` (and `\b`) are horrible predefined character classes that have pretty much no use when you're trying to build robust regular expressions. `\w` is only barely useful as something that approximates identifiers in programming languages. IMHO except for quick hacks that shouldn't even be a character class people should know about because it rarely matches what people think.

Comment: @Joey They're often pretty useful with locale-specific characters included. In [a project](https://charcoal-se.org/about) ([GitHub](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/blob/master/findspam.py)) that I participate there is an extremely intensive use of regexes (Python flavor).

Comment: I'd argue that `\p{L}` (or anything that actually matches grapheme clusters) is much more useful in such cases. The underscore is the oddball and that's only ASCII. Characters in `\w` that are not in `\p{L}` or `\p{Nd}` include combining characters, as well as a few other weird cases that I wouldn't really expect to be matched.

Comment: @Joey There are extended Unicode support in some Regex implementations.

Comment: Even /s or /d. and comboes does not really solve my issues. I will make a setting in the CRM-system that this code is run in. That setting will contain the start of the url including the right port and I run from there. Thanks for the excellent feedback.